# Github Actions R-CMD-check failing on setup-r-dependencies@v2

Tags: r, github-actions, r-package

I'm trying to setup a very simple R package and checking it with Github Actions, but all the jobs in the check fail on the same part. In Run r-lib/actions/setup-r-dependencies@v2, I get the error below in the Dependency resolution part. I'm new to this, so I have no idea where to begin fixing it. Just let me know if any more information is needed! Any help is appreciated.

```
Dependency resolution
  ℹ Creating lockfile '.github/pkg.lock'
  
  ✔ Updated metadata database: 4.26 MB in 10 files.
  
  ℹ Creating lockfile '.github/pkg.lock'
  ℹ Updating metadata database
  ✔ Updating metadata database ... done
  
  ℹ Creating lockfile '.github/pkg.lock'
  ✖ Creating lockfile '.github/pkg.lock' [11.2s]
  
  Error: 
  ! error in pak subprocess
  Caused by error: 
  ! Could not solve package dependencies:
  * deps::.: ! pkgdepends resolution error for deps::..
  Caused by error: 
  ! No root directory found in /home/runner/work/732A94_Advanced_R_Programming/732A94_Advanced_R_Programming or its parent directories. Root criterion: contains a file "DESCRIPTION" with contents matching "^Package: "
  * any::sessioninfo: dependency conflict
  * any::rcmdcheck: dependency conflict
  ---
  Backtrace:
  1. pak::lockfile_create(c(deps, extra_deps), lockfile = ".github/pkg.lock", …
  2. pak:::remote(function(...) { …
  3. err$throw(res$error)
  ---
  Subprocess backtrace:
  1. base::withCallingHandlers(cli_message = function(msg) { …
  2. get("lockfile_create_internal", asNamespace("pak"))(...)
  3. prop$stop_for_solution_error()
  4. private$plan$stop_for_solve_error()
  5. pkgdepends:::pkgplan_stop_for_solve_error(self, private)
  6. base::throw(new_error("Could not solve package dependencies:\n", msg, …
  7. | base::signalCondition(cond)
  8. global (function (e) …
  Execution halted
  Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: It seems like GitHub can't find your Description file. Or maybe it finds it, but you didn't have it filled out. Is this what you're following? 5. Fill out the DESCRIPTION file with what you find suitable. See chapter \Package metadata" in [2] for details.